# Generic Casting Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-4.0, generic-programming

I use this code to load data and convert them to a type that I get it using generic methods:

```
    public List<TResult> LoadFromeStreamFile<TResult>(string Location)
    {
        List<TResult> result = new List<TResult>();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Location);

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            result.Add((TResult)reader.ReadLine());
        }

        reader.Close();

        return result;
    }
```

but I have error in this code `result.Add((TResult)reader.ReadLine());`
How can I cast `string` to `TResult`??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That cast can't *possibly* work unless `TResult` is either `object` or `string`. Assuming you're *actually* trying to create something like an entity, I would *either* suggest you pass in a `Func<string, TResult>` or (preferrably) that you use LINQ - so you don't need this method at all:

```
var list = File.ReadLines(location)
               .Select(line => new SomeEntity(line))
               .ToList();
```

If you still want the method, you *could* use:

```
public static List<TResult> LoadFromFile<TResult>(string location,
                                                  Func<string, TResult> selector)
{
    return File.ReadLines(location).Select(selector).ToList();
}
```

... but I'm not sure whether it's worth it. I suppose if you're doing this a lot...

(On a side note, when you *do* need to read from a file, you should use a `using` statement so that your file handle gets closed even if an exception is thrown.)

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee: It would be whatever type you want to create - the type you *would* pass in as `TResult`. I'm suggesting that you probably don't need a generic method at all. Will edit.

Comment: I want to write an Assistant Classes for my project.and I saw that many times I wanted to load data but in some different types.and I want to make a generic method to Load data and return as needed Data Type.How can I Do this Without generic methods?

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee: Well you'll need to write the appropriate code to perform a conversion from a single line to a single object either way, on a per-type basis. The generic method would effectively just be a way of calling that multiple times. Whether or not you find it worth doing, or whether you just use `Select` from LINQ each time you need it is up to you.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by implementing explicit type conversion operator in "TResult".
Explicit casting from object to TResult.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

This is actually 'in a way' same as having a constructor in "TResult" which is able to create a constructor from a given object (with some assumptions).

Comment: Explicit conversion operators aren't supported by generics without a constraint on some base class, and then the result could only be that bass class. Additionally, an interface isn't much good here as you haven't got an instance to call the method on.

Comment: Edited my answer about interface usage. Did not know that generics do not support explicit conversion. Being wrong helps in learning, at leat. Thanks.